# Parsing error: Unexpected token urlEvent : Source

Tags: lightning, community

I'm getting the following error message while attempting to save a controller that is used to navigate to a lightning page (knowledge topic) in lightning communities.  Can anyone assist?  Error and code are below:

> Failed to save landingPageController.js: ESLINT_ERROR: {c:landingPage - CONTROLLER} line:col [10:4] --> Parsing error: Unexpected token urlEvent : Source

Controller code where error occurs:

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": "/clientserviceonline2/s/topic/0TO0Q0000008aIdWAI/popular-articles"
        }
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Component code snipet:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-small slds-float_right slds-popover__close slds-button_icon" title="Close dialog" onclick="{!c.gotoURL}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis:

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
 //                       ^^ opening
            "url": "/clientserviceonline2/s/topic/0TO0Q0000008aIdWAI/popular-articles"
        });
//      ^^ closing (you are missing the parenthesis)
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Based on the code you see there, any reason why this event wouldn't fire?

Comment: Are you in lightning out?

Comment: No.  I'm using communities with a custom component.